# ImageMagick: Create a textbox above a image

Tags: textbox, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to create a textbox with a specific size above an existing image, and this text must be always centered inside the created box.

How can I do this with the lib ImageMagick?

Answer (score 1):

I found this code that +/- works like I wanted

```
convert -background transparent -fill blue \
        -font Bookman-DemiItalic -size 450x50 \
        -gravity Center caption:'Some Text' \
         img_modificadas/caption_filled.png
```